# Set directory to removable drive directory in Java

Tags: java, directory, removable-storage

I have a Java program to make a copy of a file in a removable drive. But the problem is that the user will have to type in the drive letter and folder (G:\Folder\File) for the program to read the file to copy. If they do not specify then the program will read from the workspace directory, therefore any file that is specified but does not exist in the workspace directory will cause an error message. Is it possible to change the directory to the drive letter of a removable drive detected instead of the workspace in Java codes?

FileCopy.java

```
public class FileCopy 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try
        {

            System.out.print("\nFile to copy: ");
            String filename = userInput.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\nNew filename: ");
            String newname = userInput.nextLine();

            File file1 = new File(filename);
            File file2 = new File(newname);

            inStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file2);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The program will prompt the user to type in the file name (including drive letter). For example, at "File to copy: ", the user will have to type in G:\Folder\File instead of just Folder\File or just File for the program to be able to find the file to copy. I would like the directory to be set to whatever the drive letter of the removable drive is. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Your description does not make much sense.  Post your relevant code and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have added the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.listRoots()` to list all drives in the system. And ask user to select.

But it is hard to know which one is removable drive. You may still need to ask user to select if there are multiple removable drives.